# Split list in row into multiple chunked rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame where some rows contain a list of results that come back from a system. I'm trying to split those lists into smaller chunks (in the reproducible example below, chunks of 2) with each chunk as a new row. I did work out that I could use numpy's `repeat` function to duplicate the rows to have a row for each chunk I need, but then I'm not sure how to only include a chunk of the list in Result in its place. (i.e. a row should be `['SUCCESS', 'Misc]` and the next `['Doom']` vs a row of `[['SUCCESS', 'Misc'],['Doom']]`)

I know that the best solution would be to just make each item in the list a new row using `explode` but because of client requirements, this is not an option.

**Code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Result': [['SUCCESS'], ['SUCCESS'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'Pending', 'SUCCESS', 'Misc', 'Doom'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'SUCCESS']], 'Date': ['10/10/2019', '10/09/2019', '10/08/2019', '10/07/2019', '10/06/2019', '10/05/2019']}
goal = {'Result': [['SUCCESS'], ['SUCCESS'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'Pending'], ['SUCCESS'], ['FAILURE'], ['Pending', 'SUCCESS']], 'Date': ['10/10/2019', '10/09/2019', '10/08/2019', '10/07/2019', '10/06/2019', '10/05/2019', '10/04/2019']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['len_res'] = df['Result'].str.len()

def chunking(l, n):
    for i in range(0, len(l), n):
        yield l[i:i + n]


df['chunks'] = 1
for i in range(len(df)):
    if df['len_res'][i] > 2:
        df['Result'][i] = list(chunking(df['Result'][i], 2))
        df['chunks'][i] = len(df['Result'][i])
    else:
        pass
```

**Actual Output**

```
                                          Result        Date  len_res  chunks
0                                      [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019        1       1
1                                      [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019        1       1
2                                      [FAILURE]  10/08/2019        1       1
3  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS, Misc], [Doom]]  10/07/2019        5       3
4                                      [FAILURE]  10/06/2019        1       1
5                             [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019        2       1
```

**Desired Output**

```
                                          Result        Date  len_res  chunks
0                                      [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019        1       1
1                                      [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019        1       1
2                                      [FAILURE]  10/08/2019        1       1
3                             [Pending, Pending]  10/07/2019        5       3
4                                [SUCCESS, Misc]  10/07/2019        5       3
5                                         [Doom]  10/07/2019        5       3
6                                      [FAILURE]  10/06/2019        1       1
7                             [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019        2       1
```

**With** `np.repeat`

```
df = df.loc[np.repeat(df.index.values, df.chunks)]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

                                          Result        Date  len_res  chunks
0                                      [SUCCESS]  10/10/2019        1       1
1                                      [SUCCESS]  10/09/2019        1       1
2                                      [FAILURE]  10/08/2019        1       1
3  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS, Misc], [Doom]]  10/07/2019        5       3
4  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS, Misc], [Doom]]  10/07/2019        5       3
5  [[Pending, Pending], [SUCCESS, Misc], [Doom]]  10/07/2019        5       3
6                                      [FAILURE]  10/06/2019        1       1
7                             [Pending, SUCCESS]  10/05/2019        2       1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on pandas v0.25 or later, use [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
size = 2
df['Result'] = df['Result'].apply(lambda r: np.array_split(r, np.ceil(len(r) / size)))
df['chunks'] = df['Result'].str.len()

df = df.explode('Result')
```

---

`np.array_split` splits an array into `n = ceil(len(r) / size)` parts:

```
[1]     --> [[1]]
[1,2]   --> [[1,2]]
[1,2,3] --> [[1,2], [3]]
```

`explode` repeats each row for each element in the outer-most level of the array in `Result`.

Comment: This is so elegant and efficient, and does exactly what I need. Thank you so much!